# Missing minified js file in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have done a fresh installation of WordPress on AWS Elastic BeanStalk.

I am not using the root directory. I have moved the WordPress code to the public directory.

I am not able to open the page to add or edit the post/page.

I am getting the below error in Nginx logs.

I tried both WordPress 5.5.3 and 5.4.4

Any clue where the issue can be?

```
2020/12/04 12:24:47 [warn] 13851#0: *65 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi/8/00/0000000008 while reading upstream, client: 103.5.133.148, server: , request: "GET /wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock:", host: "blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/wp-admin/upload.php"
2020/12/04 12:24:48 [error] 13851#0: *68 open() "/var/www/html/public/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.5.133.148, server: , request: "GET /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/wp-polyfill.min.js?ver=7.4.4 HTTP/1.1", host: "blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"
2020/12/04 12:24:48 [error] 13851#0: *69 open() "/var/www/html/public/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/lodash.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.5.133.148, server: , request: "GET /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/lodash.min.js?ver=4.17.15 HTTP/1.1", host: "blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"
2020/12/04 12:24:49 [error] 13851#0: *68 open() "/var/www/html/public/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.5.133.148, server: , request: "GET /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react.min.js?ver=16.9.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"
2020/12/04 12:24:49 [error] 13851#0: *69 open() "/var/www/html/public/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.5.133.148, server: , request: "GET /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=16.9.0 HTTP/1.1", host: "blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"
2020/12/04 12:24:49 [error] 13851#0: *72 open() "/var/www/html/public/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/moment.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.5.133.148, server: , request: "GET /wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/moment.min.js?ver=2.22.2 HTTP/1.1", host: "blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://blog-env.eba-gnu2jhwn.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by git. I am using composer with WordPress, so had added the 'vendor/' entry in the .gitignore file.

Because of this none of the vendor folders were getting shipped to the server and hence the missing files.

I changed 'vendor/' to '/vendor' in .gitignore file. Ran 'git rm -r --cached .' and committed the code again.

It works now.